# SharePoint Column grouping in Library

Tags: grouping

I have three column in a library namely: Category , Sub-Category and Year.
The type of this column are choice.

I select a value in Category (lets say: Name), the name gets grouped.It's fine

Next,when i select a value in Sub-category (lets say; age), the  age gets grouped.it's fine.This is allowed in SharePoint out of the box feature.

Now, I want to group the subcategory based on year.
Means if i select a value 10 in year column it should give me the result whose age is 10.

How do i do that since it involve three level grouping.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OOTB SharePoint supports only two level of grouping. However, there is a step by step guide http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html to achieve this. You need SharePoint Designer to implement the solution.